# How to edit user's profile view with django

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-views

I am making a form in which the user can edit their profile, so currently I have 2 forms, one that edits the User model(first_name, Username and Email) and other one that edits the Profile model(biography).

The problem is that every time I edit, just the `User` model is the one that gets saved while the Profile model doesn't. I think that the error is in the `views.py` file.

`views.py`:

```
    def edit_profile(request):
      if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        form1 = UpdateProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid:
          form.save()
          form1.save()
          return redirect('profile')
      else:
        form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        form1 = UpdateProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        args = {
          'form': form,
          'form1': form1,
          }
        return render(request, 'profile-edit.html', args)
```

`forms.py`:

```
    class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):

      class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
          'first_name',
          'username',
          'email',
        )
        exclude = ('password',)

    class UpdateProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

      class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = (
          'bio',
          'profile_pic',
        )
        exclude = ('user',)
```

`models.py`:

```
    class Profile(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      bio = models.CharField(max_length=400, default=1)

      def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

profile-edit.html (I replaced the {{form.as_p}} and {{ form1.as_p }} to the following html code)

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="edit-profile">
        <h3>Name</h3>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" value="{{ user.first_name }}" maxlength="30" id="id_first_name">
        <h3>Username</h3>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ user.username }}" maxlength="150" required="" id="id_username">
        <h3>Bio</h3>
        <input type="text" name="bio" value="{{ user.profile.bio }}" maxlength="400" id="id_bio">
        <h3>Email</h3>
        <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ user.email }}" maxlength="254" id="id_email">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: ```if form.is_valid:``` I think you should be checking if form AND form1 are valid. Maybe that has something to do with it?
```if form.is_valid() and form1.is_valid():```

Comment: @Brenden No, somehow it didnt work can you please help me?

Comment: @Brenden wait I think the problem is on the forms.py because when updating the Profile model  has `forms.ModelForm` while the User model has `UserChengeForm` . maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: Hey. Sorry I was too late to help, though I see you figured it out. Good stuff

Comment: @Brenden dont worry about it, thank you anyways. Can you please help me in my most recent question please? it is because one of my views is not being rendered:(

Comment: Im not very good but il have a look and see if i can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error on my code, i missed to pass the .profile from the model in the views.py file

Bad

```
    form1 = UpdateProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
```

Good

```
    form1 = UpdateProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
```